# Functional problem and verifying solutions

Tags: polynomial-time

Is there a [functional problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_problem) for which there is an algorithm that can decide if a solution is a solution or not in polynomial time but we can't find a solution in polynomial time?

Let FP be the class of functional problems.

**Update:**
Every problem in FP, say $a$, has a correspondent decisione problem $a'$ (the associated decision problem $a'$ is the problem where we ask if a possible solution is a solution), I ask if there is a functional problem $a$ for which $a'$ is in P but $a$ is NOT in FP.

In this link: [Hamiltonian cycle, verifying and finding](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/117894/hamiltonian-cycle-verifying-and-finding/117904?noredirect=1#comment249178_117904)

we have instead a functional problem HC (hamiltonian cycle) for which HC' is P and HC is in FP.

Intuitively I think that the kind of problems I search, should be 'more' the problem of kind of HC. But maybe the hard part, given $a$ (with $a'$ in P), is to prove that $a$ is NOT in FP.

Comment: I refer to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_problem
The class P is the class of decision problem which are solvable in polynomial time in a Turing Machine. I ask for a functional problem for which the associated decision problem is in P (the associated decision problem is the problem where we ask if a possible solution is a solution), but the functional problem is not solvable in polynomial time.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  Are you asking whether FP = FNP?

Comment: Every problem in FP, say $a$, has a correspondent decisione problem $a'$ (the associated decision problem $a'$ is the problem where we ask if a possible solution is a solution), I ask if there is a functional problem $a$ for which $a'$ is in P but $a$ is NOT in FP.

Comment: In this link: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/117894/hamiltonian-cycle-verifying-and-finding/117904?noredirect=1#comment249178_117904

we have instead a functional problem HC (hamiltonian cycle) for which HC' is P and HC is in FP.

Comment: I don't know if asking FP=FNP is the same of my question.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are asking whether FP = FNP.  That is an open problem.  It is known that FP = FNP if and only if P = NP.  I suspect that most theoreticians expect that it's likely that P != NP, which would imply FP != FNP.  If FP != FNP, there exists a function problem whose solutions can be verified in polynomial time, but where you can't find a solution in polynomial time.  In particularly, any FNP-complete problem -- such as FSAT, say -- will have that property, if FP != FNP.  So, the FNP-complete problems are particularly good candidates for having the property you articulate.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_problem for an overview.

Comment: What if $2^n$ as a function problem is shown to require $2^n$ digits to display its solutions? What if I could verify the solutions for $2^n$ by converting the solution into binary and comparing the trailing $0-bits$ to the value of $n$ Where, $2^n$ = $solution$. https://pastebin.com/fGcSRGdU

Comment: @TravisWells, I don't see how that's relevant to my answer.  Computing the function $n \mapsto 2^n$ is not in FP (assuming the input is represented in binary).  Please don't use comments to raise new questions or seek feedback on your ideas.  Thank you.